# What is the "right" way to track a state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ticket system where a ticket can be pending, unread, replied, closed ect.  These are stored in another model called 'status' and each state has to be made manually by seeding the database before hand.

sudocode:

```
//database is seeded and creates various statuses

ticket.new(params here)
ticket.save!
//ticket status automatically set in before_create
//status = Status.find(1); 
ticket.status.description //'unread' to start

I post on it, ticket updates to replied
//ticket status automatically set in before_update
//status = Status.find(3); 
ticket.status.description //'replied'
```

BUT this is bad because when the ticket automatically updates it's state and the database hasn't been seeded (such as in factory tests) a bunch of errors come up.  What would the "right" way be to set this up?

Storing things in string literals is bad but I just don't know... exactly...

Comment: Why is `status` in a separate table and not just a column in the `ticket` table?

Comment: Not my code - started as a college term project we commissioned the students for... I assume they figured since the states are predetermined, an association id to a entry in the table holding the set of states would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the state_machine gem if you haven't already.It could be what you are looking for: https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

You use it by creating a state column in the table you want to use states and then in the model you set up the states you want.

You can easily manage states using this gem.If you need additional info or different gems you can checkout this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/392-a-tour-of-state-machines

At the end he also shows you how you can create a finite state machine from scratch if you don't want to use a gem for some reason.